# Chrome app installed as unpacked stopped working in Chrome version 47

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

We have Chrome app installed as Unpacked extension in Chrome. Till version 46, everything worked perfectly. After update to version 47, app doesn't start at all, no error, no message, nothing. It behaves the same on Windows and Linux.

We have this Chrome app installed on cca. 15 devices and it behaves all the same. Where is version 46, works fine. Where is updated Chrome 47, it just does nothing after click on app icon.

Anybody can help, give advice, hint, anything ?

Comment: Do you look for the errors on `chrome://extensions` page (there's a link "View errors")? Have you tried debugging the app? Use [Chrome Apps & Extensions Developer Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-extensions-de/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc) or `chrome://inspect/#apps`

Comment: There's no big change. I think there must be an error message on inspect views or somewhere. If possible, Can you share the app code, I'll debug it. limasdf@gmail.com

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't see link "View errors", where exactly should be ?
The problem is that the app doesn't even open. I am in `chrome://extensions` page and I click the app's icon and NOTHING happens. Normally app would open in new tab. In Chrome 47 it is not the case. I can click it milion times and I am still on extensions page.

Comment: @SunggukLim There is no problem with the app. It runs fine, if I run it using URL in Chrome 47. The only problem is when I try to run it as unpacked extension. When I click the app's icon, nothing just happens. As I wrote in comment above, I click the icon and no new tab opens, no error, no message, nothing.

Comment: @Frodik, enable `[x] Developer mode`, see also [how to debug chrome apps](https://www.google.com/#q=how%20to%20debug%20chrome%20apps)

Comment: @wOxxOm Of course I have developer mode checked. But I don't see any "View errors" link anywhere. Please read my comment carefully. I can't debug app, because IT'S NOT LAUNCHING. After clicking app's icon, nothing happens. No new tab opens. Even if the app would be buggy, new tab would open. But it's not my case. And the app works perfectly on Chrome 46, nothing has changed since, except Chrome updated itself to version 47.

Comment: @Frodik I am a Chromium contributor. if there's no visible error, then I think I can debug it from Chromium source code.  there could be various reason. if the new tab is not open, the webui(chrome://extensions) could be broken.

Comment: Or you can bisect, https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html. Get the old binary and find 'working' version and next stopped working version. and then share the version. I'm happy to find out the reason.

Comment: @SunggukLim Chrome version 46.0.2490.86 works fine. Version 47.0.2526.73 doesn't work. I have tried installing other apps as Unpacked extensions and they don't launch either !! So I can confidently say it has nothing to do with my particular app, but it is something wrong with Chrome itself. I would be more than happy if you could look at it and share some insights.

Comment: @Frodik My app(https://github.com/beagleterm/beagle-term) as unpacked extension launch well on version 47.0.25.2673 Windows. Have you tried uninstall Chrome and reinstall chrome ?   I'm looking for the difference between two version you mentioned.

Comment: and you can see the chrome log. See https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so for anybody else affected with the same issue as I was, I post this answer. And it is very short. 
I had in my `manifest.json` file this parameter:

```
"kiosk_only" : true
```

Apperently Chrome changed its behaviour from tolerating this parameter to just silently ignoring whole app with this parameter enabled.

After many hours, I have found out this by looking at chrome_debug.log, which pointed out @SunggukLim in the comments above.

Comment: It looks like `kiosk_only` app should not be installed on normal mode. I'll file an issue about it.

Comment: @SunggukLim Exactly ! I was hoping in the past, that some day the `kiosk_only` will be eventually implemented (or better say enabled) on regular desktop Chrome. However I was not counting on that it will be silently dropped without error message. Yes, you are right, if `kiosk_only` is not supported, then Chrome shouldn't even allow installation of such app with some error message.

Comment: All right. this issue is fixed. it can be verified with chrome canary from tomorrow